# Conversion of a varchar date type to a datetime Error SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, varchar, getdate

I'm working with the following SQL Query and I'm getting the following error: Msg

> 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT        customer_del_hist.customer_number, MAX(customer_del_hist.serve_location) AS serve_location, MAX(customer_del_hist.product_number) AS product_number, 
                         MAX(customer_del_hist.del_date) AS del_date, MAX(order_rte_bal.warehouse) AS warehouse, MAX(order_rte_bal.route_number) AS route_number, 
                         MAX(order_rte_bal.route_day) AS route_day
FROM            customer_del_hist INNER JOIN
                         inv_master ON customer_del_hist.product_number = inv_master.product_number INNER JOIN
                         order_header ON customer_del_hist.order_number = order_header.order_number INNER JOIN
                         order_rte_bal ON order_header.warehouse_number = order_rte_bal.warehouse AND order_header.route_number = order_rte_bal.route_number AND
                         order_header.route_day = order_rte_bal.route_day AND order_header.delivery_date = order_rte_bal.route_date
WHERE        (customer_del_hist.del_date BETWEEN '5/01/2015' AND '7/31/2015') AND (inv_master.inventory_category IN ('02', '03', '60', '74')) AND 
                         (customer_del_hist.customer_number NOT IN
                             (SELECT        h2.customer_number
                               FROM            customer_del_hist AS h2 INNER JOIN
                                                         inv_master AS i ON h2.product_number = i.product_number
                               WHERE        (h2.del_date BETWEEN '6/01/2014' AND '4/31/2015') AND (i.inventory_category IN ('02', '03', '60', '74'))))
GROUP BY customer_del_hist.customer_number
```

I've looked at the date in the necessary table and it displays similar to the following: 2014-05-21 00:00:00.000. Any thoughts on a work around or a fix?

Comment: are you sure there is not invalid data in that column, maybe something like `2014-13-01 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually that there are only 30 days in April, not 31.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior of CAST and CONVERT with datetime character strings is governed by SET DATEFORMAT. If your date format is dmy (day/month/year), your literal '7/31/2015' may be getting interpreted as {Month: 31, Day: 7, Year: 2015}, which is not a valid date.

See here: 
[SET DATEFORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

One thing that will help you in these cases is to always use ISO 8601 format for these literals. This will bypass the interpretation behavior of CAST and CONVERT.

For your case, you could rewrite it as:

```
customer_del_hist.del_date BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-07-31'
```